# Is it bad practice to nest one java web project inside another?

Tags: java

I inherited a project at work that includes one java web app nested within another.  The higher level app has its own META-INF and WEB-INF directories, and the associated context.xml and web.xml within each.

Also at that higher level, is a directory that contains another set of INF directories and another set of context.xml and web.xml files within those.  Basically, something like this:

```
App1
|--META-INF
  |_context.xml    
|--WEB-INF
  |_web.xml 
  |_lib  
|--Generic Directory     
|--App2
  |--META-INF
    |_context.xml    
  |--WEB-INF
    |_web.xml 
    |_lib 
  |--Another Generic Directory
```

Being relatively new to Java, I'm curious if this is considered bad practice.  My initial thought is to restructure the project because I'm concerned users would be able to access the second set of xml files which are normally hidden from view.

Answer (score 0):

What is the purpose of having the App2 directory here ? À webapp (WAR) cannot contain another webapp (WAR) so yes it is a bad practice since it has no interest.

Comment: The previous developer who created the structure is no longer with the company, so I can't really say what their intent was.  I'm just curious if there is a scenario in which this structure could be beneficial.

Comment: Maybe hé wanted to expose source content of App2 through App1. But content of App2 won't be executed.